# CORS error from fetch call but none from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, cors

I'm working on small project for fun that I started as a Node script, using axios to make a GET call to an API. I got it working and decided I wanted to move it to a normal script to be used in an html file, so I moved it to an html file between `<script></script>` tags and made some changes to make it a bit cleaner with ES6 which as far as I know shouldn't have broken anything, but now I'm getting the error `(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)`. From what I've gathered, this is something that the server has to set so there's not much I can do. I'm just not sure why it worked with Node?

Here's the gist of my code:
NodeJS:

```
axios('url_here')
    .then(data => {/* Some processing here */})
```

Standalone JS in HTML file:

```
const data = await (await fetch('url_here')).json();
/* Same processing here as what I did in Node */
```

Comment: CORS is only implemented in browsers as a browser-specific security feature.  Any tool that is not a browser such as making http requests from nodejs will not be subject to any CORs restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

CORS checks are a browser security feature. That's the reason it works in Node.js but not in a browser.

*"The CORS mechanism supports secure cross-origin requests and data transfers between **browsers** and servers. Modern **browsers** use CORS in APIs such as XMLHttpRequest or Fetch to mitigate the risks of cross-origin HTTP requests."* [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Ah well that would definitely be it then! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a GET call to server then you need to provide this in axios call like

```
axios.get('url')
```

**OR**

```
axios({method: 'get', url: 'your_url'})
```

Comment: _"I got it working"_ The `axios` call is already working. The `fetch` isn't working because of the CORS policy. `axios('url')` is also valid. It sends a `GET` request. See the example `axios('/user/12345');` on https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro